# Better Method than using setter in typescript : private variables are declared but value not read issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, class, getter-setter

I have a scenario like this:

```
class Employee {
  private fullName: string;
  private firstName: string;
  private lastName: string;
  private age: number;
  private isValid: boolean;

  constructor() {
    this.fullName = null;
    this.firstName = null;
    this.lastName = null;
    this.age = null;
    this.isValid = false;
  }

  setfullName(fullName: string) {
    this.fullName = fullName;
  }

  setfirstName(firstName: string) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
  }

  setlastName(lastName: string) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
  }

  setAge(age: number) {
    this.age = age;
  }

  setValid(isValid: boolean) {
    this.isValid = isValid;
  }
}

// test.ts file
let employee = new Employee();

// set in different positions in test.ts file based on getting the input paramters
employee.setfullName("james cooper");
employee.setfirstName("mary");
employee.setlastName("fransis"); // getting lastName from another api call
employee.setAge(50); // getting 50 from another api call
employee.setValid(true);
```

Here i am getting a warning in vscode like "private variables are declared but its value is not read". 
Inorder to prevent this warning, i have to use getter method, but here purpose is to save the object properties and not reading. So getter method seems to be useless.
Since i am new to typescript, without setting these variables to public or disabling in tslint configuration, can anybody suggest a better approach for the same?

The purpose is to set the employee info, for that I created Employee model.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You don't have any getters, so the values are indeed not read and cannot be read since they are private

Comment: What would be the purpose of saving data if it won't ever be read?

Comment: What's is the point of saving data without reading it anywhere?

Comment: @vicnoob : we are passing these employee object directly to frontend..

Comment: then that should be public? private method, variable should only be used in that class

Comment: @vicnoob My doubt is like if we change to public, then these variables are access outside Employee class method, correct? What i am trying to do is save the value of these objects and send to front end, So i am wondering whether we need to make it public. correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @Vishnu As I am working with angular, private variable can not be used on template on production mode, it MUST BE public, otherwise compiler error will fired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're not doing anything with the data on this side other than assigning to properties of it, it sounds like you should be creating a plain object instead. Since in your original code, all the methods which set properties are public, and don't do anything else, they don't accomplish anything useful. If an external source can call a setter method, it may as well just assign a property directly. The `class` adds unnecessary and confusing overhead, and part of that is why Typescript is complaining. Instead, do something like:

```
type Employee = Partial<{
    fullName: string;
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    age: number;
    isValid: boolean;
}>;
const employee: Employee = {};
employee.age = 15;
employee.isValid = false;
// send employee to front-end
```

IMO, a class is generally useful only when you need to have data associated with an instance *and* methods which retrieve and use the data in some way.